# Read lines in C# without losing newline characters

Tags: c#, string

At the moment, I am using C#'s inbuilt `StreamReader` to read lines from a file.

As is well known, if the last line is blank, the stream reader does not acknowledge this as a separate line. That is, a line must contain text, and the newline character at the end is optional for the last line.

This is having the effect on some of my files that I am losing (important, for reasons I don't want to get into) whitespace at the end of the file each time my program consumes and re-writes specific files.

Is there an implementation of `TextReader` available either as a part of the language or as a NuGet package which provides the `ReadLine` functionality, but retains the new line characters (whichever they may be) as a part of the line so that I can exactly reproduce the output? I would prefer not to have to roll my own method to consume line-based input.

Edit: it should be noted that I cannot read the whole file into memory.

Comment: If you want to read newlines then use `StreamReader.Read()` instead of `ReadLine()` and accumulate the characters that are important to you.

Comment: @DourHighArch Yep, I could do that - however I wanted to check that this (I thought) obvious case hadn't already been handled in a wrapped way (e.g. as an implementation of TextReader, as per the question).

Comment: That is not how StreamReader works, you do can an empty string from a trailing blank line in the text file.  Fix the bug, not the class.

Comment: @Hans, I beg to differ, since it is exactly the behaviour I am observing. Using a text file with 3 lines with text in, and nothing on the last line (which does not terminate with a newline), I see three lines of text and then the stream reader returns null.

Comment: Sound to me that you are confused about how your text viewer/editor works.  Just pare it down to the basics, create a text file with your editor, don't type anything and only press the Enter key.  Verify that StreamReader will return one empty string, then null.

Comment: Yes it does... and if I type enter then a thing on the second line, I don't get null for that second line (obviously). The point being, it is presently impossible for me to detect using the ReadLine function of the string reader class whether the last line was terminated using a new line or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private readonly char newLineMarker = Environment.NewLine.Last();
private readonly char[] newLine = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray();
private readonly char eof = '\uffff';

private IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(string path)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        char c;
        string line;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((c = (char)sr.Read()) != eof)
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            if (c == newLineMarker &&
                (line = sb.ToString()).EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
            {
                yield return line.Trim(newLine);

                sb.Clear();
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        if (sb.Length > 0)
            yield return sb.ToString().Trim(newLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to say I am impressed that you did that... I'll try it out tomorrow to see if it works!

Comment: Good luck! I tested the code, so I'm sure it should work.

Comment: I am marking this correct as it allowed me to generate a more fully fledged solution.

Comment: Great! Glad for you!

Answer (score 4):

You can combine [`ReadToEnd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=netframework-4.7.2) with [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get in an array the content of your file, including the empty lines.

I don't recommend you to use `ReadToEnd()` if your file is big.

In example :

```
string[] lines;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
    var WholeFile = sr.ReadToEnd();
    lines = WholeFile.Split('\n');
}
```

Comment: This will work, but some of the files are very large and don't fit into memory like this. Sorry that I failed to include that detail!

Comment: @PhilipAdler how about just chunking it up yourself custom with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readblock?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @kenny chunking was my second option.

Comment: @kenny I had considered this, but I wanted to know specifically if this had already been implemented and "wrapped up nice" before going and re-inventing the wheel.